# localhost appending itself before the backend api in angular

Tags: angular, http, mean-stack, mean

i have put my backend to aws. the backend url works finein postman.

but when i put my backend url in angular service, locahost is getting appended to it in front.

how can i resolve this.

backend url: api.angularapp.site

in my service i called like this:

```
private url = "api.angularapp.site/api/v1";

public signupFunction(data):Observable<any>{

    const params=new HttpParams()
    .set('firstName', data.firstName)
    .set('lastName', data.lastName)
    .set('mobileNumber', data.mobile)
    .set('email', data.email)
    .set('password', data.password)
    .set('gender',data.gender)
    .set('profilePic',data.profilePic);

    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/users/signup`,params);
  }//end of signup function
```

but when i run the app and try to signup i get console error:

***http://localhost:4200/api.angularapp.site/api/v1/users/signup 404 (Not Found)***

why is this localhost attaching itself to the backend call url.

before the url was 
** private url = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1";**
in that case angular was connecting fine to backend.
but now i am not getting how it is appending angular locahost url in start

Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to provide a full qualified url to the service, otherwise angular will try to do a relative url.

change the url variable to

```
private url = "http://api.angularapp.site/api/v1";
```

and all should work.